# What is the word for left thirds?

Tags: after-effects, animation, adobe

There is lower thirds in which a title and sometimes, a subtitle appears. They usually appears at bottom left of the screen. However, I am looking for examples in which a speaker (or focus of object) is on the right side of the screen and the text and graphics animate in on the left side of the screen.

I couldn't find any good examples of text animation that animate in on the left side. It should be something like [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFSia1LZI4Y).

This is the video that I am using, [Medical colleagues chatting](https://www.istockphoto.com/video/medical-colleagues-chatting-in-a-stairwell-of-a-hospital-gm484157288-71668137). There's plenty of space at the left side in which I was planning to add the logo and three bullet points.

I wanted to find some good simple text animations for left side in adobe after effects or some free templates or something like that.

So what keywords should I use to search for left side thirds?

Comment: I don't have a word for it,  I always called it left third or left panel,  and had my title artist build what we needed